# how to use php JavaBridge without allow_url_include = On?

Tags: php, php-java-bridge

I am using php JavaBridge library,

the thing is, I need to include the php client library directly from server using
require_once "someremoteurl.com"

For this allow_url_include should be enabled, but I am in situation where this should be avoided.

Is there anyone who did this before? Is there any workaround?

I tried downloading file real-time using fread and then including it from local, but it does not work somehow, giving some php error inside JavaBridge class... I do not see any difference though.

Comment: `file_get_contents('remote file'); file_put_contents('localfile', $remote_contents); include('localfile');`

Comment: It should work I agree, but it does not, when done that way, there is a access forbidden error from tomcat, occurring in Java.inc on line 869

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Marc B, used the following code:

```
$remote_contents = file_get_contents($url); 
file_put_contents($local, $remote_contents);

include($local);
```

Didn't work on first try, but worked after adding this line before the include:

```
define ("JAVA_SERVLET", "/WordBridge/servlet.phpjavabridge");
```